# Cross-client devtools synchronisation

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, frontend, firebug

I just recently had a common situation, where I had to tweak a finished design a little bit.

Two boxes should get new background/font colors. 
The normal way is to wait till the designer sends in the new screens that are approved by the client.

To speed up the process it would be great if client, designer and frontend developer just have a conference and the frontend developer is playing with the colors and Designer and Client can see the changes in realtime.

I just stumbled upon Crossfire https://github.com/mrennie/crossfire/wiki/Connecting-Firebug-to-Firebug-with-Crossfire
but this seems to be a little bit complicated to set up.

So my question is, is there an easy way (for non techis) to sync changes in Chrome devtools or Firebug across multiple computers?

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome DevTools as well as the Firefox DevTools allow remote debugging to enable debugging between one server and one client:

In Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging

In Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Though as far as I know they do not allow multiple clients.

So one simple way to work together that way is by making a video conference and the front-end developer shares his screen.